# Canon T5i (lp-e8) high capacity battery grip/battery bank?

Tags: battery, battery-grip, power-supply, power

I have two Canon lp-e8 batteries that I use for my T5i but they run out of battery pretty quickly (only 1,120 mAh each) and then I'm left with nothing.

I have a 15,000 mAh battery bank that I use for charging my GoPro and other devices and it seems to work pretty well for that and was left wondering if there was something like that for Canon cameras but in grip form. Just was wondering if anybody knows of any battery grips that come with a built in battery cell. Looking for something with about 5,000-10,000 mAh of power. If anyone knows of something similar to what I'm talking about I'd really appreciate a reply.

Thanks in advance for any answer I may receive!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Canon offers an AC adapter for the T5i the AC Adapter Kit ACK-E8, it is a power supply and a blank / dummy battery that goes in the regular battery chamber. The dummy battery has a common connector on the base that the AC kit plugs in to.

If the voltage of your external battery pack is ok then this might be the simplest way to power your camera from your external pack.

Answer (score 0):

Get a standard battery grip and hunt for some higher mAh batteries off ebay. There will be some 2,500mah or maybe even higher, and they should be reasonably priced too. Grips hold 2 batteries so that would give you 5,000mah in the body, and keep 2 spares charged and with you (assuming changing batteries is not an issue - eg you're not doing timelapse stuff etc). Some grips take a bigger battery pack also, not aware of any for the t5i off the top of my head though.